# Sudden "package doesn't exist" in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, java-package

Recently I started to receive the following errors about random packages:

[image]

`mvn` build is working of course, the problem is only for building within Idea.

Sometimes I can fix it with reloading maven project, sometimes I can't.

"Disappeared" package is listed both in `pom` and in the list of libraries:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to run "Fiel | Invalidate Caches" and then "Reload" from Maven tool window?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know if it has guaranteed result. Currently I am reloading maven and exiting/entering IDE several times. During this a different packages can appear/disappear.

Comment: Did you update recently to **2021.1** version?

Answer (score 0):

Reopen IntelliJ again. On the top right corner choose Maven- perform clean and install for the module in which you face this error:- "Package does not exist"